# Child is same size as parent, but scroll appears

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am adding a new widget with SVG in it.

I am making it same size as parent, but it results in unwanted scroll to appear.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Murval/j1oe6x4b/

```css
.widget-outer {
  display: flex;
  height: 210px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.widget {
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1;
}

.svg-container {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.svg {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget-outer">
  <div class="widget">
    <div class="svg-container">
      <svg class="svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" style="fill: gray;"></circle>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As I see, the scroll appears, because there is extra space below *svg-container* div. But changing display, as was suggested in other posts, has no effect.

**Extra considerations:**

- I don't want to change styles for *widget-outer* and *widget* classes, because they are working fine for other widgets. **overflow-y: auto** on *widget* class is required, becuase some other widgets have longer content that should be scrollable.
- I want *svg* element to take all available space in *widget* for any combination of height and width on *widget-container*.
- Decreasing **max-height** of *svg* element is helping, but can not be counted as proper solution to this problem.

tl;dr Is it possible to fit *svg* in *widget* without scrollbar?

Comment: Changing both `.svg-container` and `.svg` to `display: block` removes the scrollbar.

Comment: beacuse you have made svg `inline-block` a space will be added after it unless you comment out all space between the end of the svg-container and the start of the next div end tag - either make it block or comment out the space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change *both* `.svg-container` and `.svg` to `display: block`

```css
.widget-outer {
  display: flex;
  height: 210px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.widget {
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1;
}

.svg-container {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.svg {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget-outer">
  <div class="widget">
    <div class="svg-container">
      <svg class="svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" style="fill: gray;"></circle>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The SVG element is vertically positioned at baseline. That's why it's taking 4px extra space at the bottom of it. Just tell it to get vertically aligned at the top and you will get the desired result. Just change you css from

```
.svg {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

to

```
.svg {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to set `vertical-align: middle;` on the `svg`. This will keep the expected behavior on your given layout, which `display: block` might not.

```css
.widget-outer {
  display: flex;
  height: 210px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.widget {
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1;
}

.svg-container {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.svg {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget-outer">
  <div class="widget">
    <div class="svg-container">
      <svg class="svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" style="fill: gray;"></circle>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In my particular case `display: block;` was better solution, I assume, but this is a good alternative. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That's a strange behavior. Even I'm looking for technical reason behind it.

For the time-being you can remove the scrollbar - by making two changes:

1. remove `display: inline-block;` from `.svg-container` class
2. Add `float:left` to `SVG` element. or `display` also works.

```css
.widget-outer {
  display: flex;
  height: 210px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.widget {
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1;
}

.svg-container {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.svg {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget-outer">
  <div class="widget">
    <div class="svg-container">
      <svg class="svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" style="fill: gray;"></circle>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is nothing "strange" about it. All inline and inline-block elements have default spacing around them.

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution I found to remove the scroll

```
.widget {
    overflow:hidden;
    flex: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A super hack if the parent is `display:block` and child is `display:inline-block` is to set in the parent:

```
font-size: 0px;
line-height: 0px;
```